# Access violation when trying to check if char* is double

Tags: c++, access-violation

Good day everyone. I'm having an error at runtime. I'm trying to check if the token is double but I'm receiving an error "Fault: access violation at 0x40516B: read of address 0x0".. What causes the error and what can I do to prevent the error? is there any other way to check if a token is double or alphanumeric? thanks..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio>
#include <string>
#include <ctype>
#include <stdlib>

char statement[256];
string strStatement;
string variableName[5];
double values[5];
int counter = 0;
double result=0;
string stmtFormat =" ";
char * tokens;
string newString;

bool isDouble(char *toCheck)
{
  bool valid = true;
  for(int i=0 ; i <(sizeof(toCheck)/sizeof(toCheck[0]));i++)
  {
    if((i!=0 && toCheck[i]=='-')||(toCheck[i]!='0'||toCheck[i]!='1'||toCheck[i]!='2'||toCheck[i]!='3'||toCheck[i]!='4'||toCheck[i]!='5'||toCheck[i]!='6'||toCheck[i]!='7'||toCheck[i]!='8'||toCheck[i]!='9'))
    {
      bool valid = false;
      cout<<"invalid number";
      break;
    }
  }
  return valid;
}

void checkGrammar(string strStatement)
{    
  if(strStatement == "print;")
  {
    cout<<"-----Output of the program-----"<<endl;
    cout<<"The result is "<<result;
  }
  else
  {
    tokens = strtok (statement," ");
    while(tokens!= NULL)
    {
      tokens = strtok(NULL ," ");
      if (tokens == "    " ){stmtFormat = stmtFormat+"<opr>";}
      else if (tokens == "-" ){stmtFormat = stmtFormat+"<opr>";}
      else if (tokens == "*" ){stmtFormat = stmtFormat+"<opr>";}
      else if (tokens == "/" ){stmtFormat = stmtFormat+"<opr>";}
      else if (tokens == "^" ){stmtFormat = stmtFormat+"<opr>";}
      else if (tokens == ";"){stmtFormat = stmtFormat+"<end>";}
      else //not operands or end
      {
        if (isDouble(tokens)){stmtFormat = stmtFormat+"<val>";}
        else{}
      }
    }
  }
}

main(void)
{
  cout <<"\nInstructions: you can declare up to 5 variables. use this syntax: \n \"num var_name = value ; \" (without the \"\")    "<<endl;
  cout <<"use , instead of . for decimals.   \n";
  cout <<"Afterwards, type the expression that you want."<<endl;
  cout <<"To print;, just type: print"<<endl;
  cout <<"Let's start!\n\n";
  while(strStatement != "print;")
  {
    cout<< ">";
    cin    getline(statement, 256);
    strStatement = statement;
    checkGrammar(strStatement);
  }
  getch();
}
```

Comment: `read of address 0x0` means that you are trying to dereference a `null` pointer. Why are you using `tokens = strtok(NULL ," ");` on `tokens`? Also, `checkGrammar` cannot compare two strings with the `==` sign: use `strcmp()` instead.

Comment: You've asked a vague question, dumped a lot of code here, and provided no input that cause the failure. You haven't even bothered to trim the irrelevant parts of your code a little bit. Any answer you get will be an act of extreme generosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What causes the error

Doing `tokens = strtok(NULL ," ");` twice at the beginning of the while loop looks pretty wrong:

```
 tokens = strtok (statement," ");
 while(tokens!= NULL)
 {
     tokens = strtok(NULL ," "); // tokens might become NULL here!
```

IMHO it's better readable and more safe to put this in a `for` loop:

```
 for(tokens = strtok (statement," "); tokens != NULL; strtok (NULL ," "))
 {
    // ...
 }
```

Note that `tokens` may become `NULL` after the call inside the while loop, and is passed unchecked to `isDouble()` in the `else` part. This might quite probably be your problem.

> and what can I do to prevent the error?

Always check pointers for non NULL values before dereferencing them.

Answer (score 0):

`isalpha`, `isdigit`, or `isalnum` in `<cctype>` can be used for specific characters in a loop like you have but I'd use `std::string` and more C++ if possible.

That said your AV is caused by the fact the you will eventually have no more string tokens to retrieve and `strtok` will return NULL and you don't want to be accessing a nullptr with `operator[]` ... you can add a null check in your isDouble method as a quick hack:

```
bool isDouble(char *toCheck)
{
  bool valid = toCheck != 0;
  if ( valid ) {
   for(int i=0 ; i <(sizeof(toCheck)/sizeof(toCheck[0]));i++)
   {
    if((i!=0 && toCheck[i]=='-')||(toCheck[i]!='0'||toCheck[i]!='1'||toCheck[i]!='2'||toCheck[i]!='3'||toCheck[i]!='4'||toCheck[i]!='5'||toCheck[i]!='6'||toCheck[i]!='7'||toCheck[i]!='8'||toCheck[i]!='9'))
      {
        bool valid = false;
         cout<<"invalid number";
         break;
      }
   }}
   return valid;
}
```

however catching it in the loop may be better

```
  char* tokens = strtok (statement, " ");
  while (tokens != NULL)
  {
    // do stuff
    tokens = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems:

1: Global variables usually seem like a good idea at first.
They're not. Get rid of them.

2: You're modifying a different variable than you think in `isDouble`.
The inner declaration hides the outer one.

3: You're comparing a `char*` to a literal.
Don't do that, it's a pointer comparison. None of the comparisons will be true.

4: You're calling `strtok` *after* checking if the result was `NULL`.
(A not uncommon beginners' misunderstanding is that a loop will stop as soon as the condition is false. It won't.)
The last time, when it *is* `NULL`, is probably when you crash.
Move the call inside the loop so it's last instead of first.